# Azure Logic app - Error Fetching API Definition

Tags: azure, logic, workflow

When I try to add SQL Connector to my Logic App, I get the below error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems a temporal error of comunication between APIs. The portal is still in preview and that kind of erros can happen.

Answer (score -1):

disable the swagger thing in SwaggerConfig.cs that you would have enabled to test the API locally, and then republish.

```
/*      })
    .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
   {
 */
```